# NIFI gives exception during InvokeHTTP execution

Tags: hadoop, post, apache-nifi

Issue: Call Rest API using NIFI InvokeHTTP Processor, it gives below error. 
Generate token working Fine and this API is working fine on POSTMASTER tool and token passing using Authorization Bearer "token".
I need guidance on this.
I am new to NIFI.

[image: NIFI Rest API Error]

Comment: Failed to connect. You have to check ability to connect to host/port from machine where nifi is running.

Comment: Some time working fine, sometime gives exception.

Comment: Have you scheduled it for 0 sec? If yes, then it is possible that server is not able respond your request continuously. So try to change schedule time from 0 sec to 5 or 10 sec and see...

Comment: Yes its 5 sec, and try with 10sec no luck